# Jquery for loop write html after every third iteration of loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops

I am trying to get a `<div class="clear"></div>` to appear after every third iteration of a for loop in jquery.  I know in PHP it can be accomplished via `if($i%3 == 0)` but how does one do it in jquery/javascript?

Here is my for loop:

```
var data = $.parseJSON(result);
for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    if(i/3 == 1){
        $('#add_product_preview_area').append('<div class="clear"></div>');
    }
    $('#add_product_preview_area').append(data[i]);
}
```

Now this only works once since the loop will only get to the number 3 once.  So any thoughts on how to make the same php concept work in jquery?  I have seen the other questions about wrapping every nth in a div, but I just need to write the html of a div after each one.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

```
if ( i && (i % 3 === 0)) {
```

Is the answer..I didn't know you could do that.  Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you use the same logic here?

Comment: Did you try what you did in PHP with JavaScript? You might be surprised.

Comment: The '%' modulus operator still exists: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821006/find-if-variable-is-divisible-by-2

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use the modulus operator instead.

```
if ( i && (i % 3 === 0)) { ...
```

Whenever there's no remainder, you're evenly divisible by `3`.

I included the `i &&` to eliminate the first iteration since `0 % 3 === 0; // true`.

Comment: I swear i had already tried the php method and it didn't work..woops.  thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Use this... just like your PHP

```
if (i % 3 == 0 )
```