# How to check the sum of a divison with javascript?

Tags: javascript, math

I want to check For EXAMPLE:

> 12 - 13 - 14 - 15
>
> 12 / 3 = 4 -> OK.
>
> 13 / 3 = 4.33 -> NOT OK.
>
> 14 / 3 = 4.67 -> NOT OK.
>
> 15 / 3 = 5 -> OK.

I want to create a while loop where i use the number i want to divide to 3 as "x".

so:

```
var x = 0
while (x<20) {
//SOMETHING HERE
x++;
}
```

Something like that but i dont know the command to check if the sum is a decimal number or not.

Than i want to see the "OK. numbers" in my web browser with a `documetn.write( OK numbers )`

Comment: [modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)

Comment: how to use modulo? can you give me an example code for javascript?

Comment: [Find if variable is divisible by 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821006/find-if-variable-is-divisible-by-2) This is 2, but the same applies for 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [modulo operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) to check if a number is divisible by another.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TrrV8/)

```
var x = 0;
while (x < 20) {
    if (x % 3 === 0) {
        document.write(x + ' ');
    }
    x++;
}
```

Also, the W3C recommends against using `document.write` now. Instead it is better to use `document.createElement` to create an element and insert it that way, like this:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Nu3EG/)

```
var span = document.createElement('span');
span.innerHTML = text;
document.body.appendChild(span);
```

Comment: Than how can i use each x variable in a addition as: `x1 + x2 +... + xEND` and `document.write(sum of all the x)`